# print $_COOKIE display nothing BUT firefox display the cookie

Tags: php, setcookie

I am working on a local project, Here is my function to create the cookie:

`setcookie('remember-me', "large and complex key", time() + $une_semaine);`

Even after reloading the page nothing is displayed... print_r display only the PHPSESSID and not my cookie BUT when I watch coockies on Firefox parameters I can see him, he is effectively created, so whats wrong ??

Im blocked, could you help me guys please?

Comment: what is the value of $une_semaine?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
setcookie('remember-me', "large and complex key", time() + 60*60*24*365);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.

The problem was that my cookie was not accessible from every parts of the website, to solve this add '/' on 5th parameter of setcookie method, like that:

setcookie($key, $val, time() + 60*60*24*7, **'/'**);